# Precaution steps on qualitative analysis (inorganic salts)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I will carry out the experiment on determine the cation and anions of inorganic substances (magnesium thiosulphate, aluminium ion and ammonium ion) on Wednesday. I am looking for the precaution steps for this experiment. Anybody can answer my question?

Comment: What are precaution steps? You should be careful not to ingest toxic compounds and people call that precautions. You should also be careful not to mess up the experiment which people still call precautions. Please [edit] and be more clear about what exactly you need to know.